# Can't parse from String to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, org.json

Im using the following code to convert from a well-formed-String to a JSONObject in Java:

```
public void getStatus(){
    String status = "";
    try{
        String line;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url;
        url = new URL("http://bromio.com.mx/explore/PointOfInterestService.svc/GetData");
        BufferedReader rd;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        Log.d("JSON: ", result.toString());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it's throwing an exception, it seems that i cannot cast that specific string to JSONObject.
The JSON can be acceses in this page: (It's too big to show!) http://bromio.com.mx/explore/PointOfInterestService.svc/GetData
Any help solving this problem will help me a lot. thank you

Comment: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) says that json is invalid. Can you have escaped `"` in json? Also the json cannot start and end with `"`, so there's that.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace so we can see what the error is.

Comment: That source is a JSON string, not a JSON object. It starts with a double-quote, ends with a double-quote, and escapes double quotes and unicode sequences internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the first few characters of your json

```
 "{ \"poi\":[\u000d\u000a  
 ^  ^    ^   ^^^^^^
 |  |    |      |-----------> not sure about all this
 |  |    -------------------> not acceptable in json
 |  ------------------------> not acceptable in json
 ---------------------------> not acceptable in json
```

What you get back from that website is not valid root json. Fix your source if you have control over it. Or use the String utility methods to replace those characters.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll have to substring the JSON to delete the "special" characters since i have no idea what are there for

Comment: All these things are simply an escaped json string. `\u000d`, for instance, is the unicode code point 0x000d. See http://www.json.org. Simply deleting them won't get you what you want.

Comment: @yshavit The unicode bits are chill, they're just CR LF. The initial and trailing `"` and the backslashes in `\"` are not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What I meant is that if the OP tries to fix the string by just deleting the `\\`, it won't get what they want. If I misunderstood the proposed next step, I'll apologize and step quietly away. :)

Comment: @yshavit I guess I didn't spell it out. But even if OP tries, they'll correct themselves easily enough.